# Meteor Mongo, accessing array of objects

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have an Invoices collection, which has _id(invoice id) and transactions(array of object), this transactions field has **amount** and **reference** as property, now I have invoice id and transaction reference and I am not sure how to loop through transaction searching for reference field.

this is my try,

transids contains all transaction _id

```
const final = Invoices.find({
   invoiceId: filter.invoiceID,
   transactions: { $in: transids }
 }).map(function (obj) {
   return {
     text: obj.reference,
   };
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather related to the `map` function. The `obj` of the map function is your current invoice document, because you searched for documents in `Invoices`.

So if you want to get the text for all the transactions you have found, you need to traverse all transactions for the current invoice doc.

The following example maps each invoice doc to a doc, where it's transaction docs are mapped to texts by reference.

```
const final = Invoices.find({
   invoiceId: filter.invoiceID,
   transactions: { $in: transids }
 }).map(function (obj) {
    const transactions = obj.transactions.map(function(transaction){ 
        return {
            text: transaction.reference,
        };
    });
    obj.transactions = transactions;
    return obj;
 });
```

Note: if reference is just an id to another doc, you need to call the corresponding collection.

```
const ref = ReferenceCollection.findOne(transaction.reference); 
//ReferenceCollection is a placeholder here
return {
    text: ref.text,
};
```